# conjugate bundle

Tags: vector-bundles, holomorphic-bundles

The conjugate bundle $\bar{E}$ of a complex vector bundle E is defined as a complex vector bundle which is the same smooth manifold as E and same projection map but on each fiber has the complex conjugate action.

Here are some question I have in mind for conjugate bundle:

1. Suppose E is holomorphic vector bundle. Is its conjugate bundle still holomorphic?
2. I know that $\bar{E}$ is isomorphic to $E^{*}$ as complex vector bundle when $E$ is equipped with a Hermitian structure.  If $E$ is holomorphic , then there is a fact $E^{*}$ is also holomorphic. My question is can the isomorphism between $\bar{E}$ and $E^{*}$ be a holomorphic isomorphism?
3. Suppose $E$ is the holomorphic cotangent bundle $(T_{\mathbb{C}}^{(1,0)}M)^{*}$ of some complex manifold $M$. What is $\bar{E}$ then? Is it $(T_{\mathbb{C}}^{(0,1)}M)^{*}$?

Thanks for any explaination!

Answer (score 2):

I thought I figured some out.

1. The transition function for $\bar{E}$ should be ($\bar{g_{ij}}$) if the transition function for $E$ is ($g_{ij}$). So if $E$ is holomorphic, i.e. ($g_{ij}$) holomorphic, then ($\bar{g_{ij}}$) must be anti holomorphic. So for the first one, the answer is negative.
2. As $E^{*}$ is holomorphic, this isomorphism is not a holomorphic one.  The regularity of the isomorphic should correspond to the regularity of the Hermitian metric. This isomorphism takes ($\bar{g}$) to $(g^{-1})^{*}$. So it's eqivalent to say it provides a reduction for the structure group from GL(2n,R) to O(2n), where n= complex rank of $E$, when we view the hermitian structure as a bilinear map on $E \times \bar{E}$.
3. For the third one, the answer is yes if checking the transition function of $(T_{\mathbb{C}}^{(0,1)}M)^{*}$

Comment: I think $\bar E$ *is* actually a holomorphic vector bundle, albeit in an unexpected way. Let $\varphi_\alpha : \pi^{-1}(\bar U_\alpha) \to U_\alpha \times \mathbb C^k$ be the local trivializations of $E$ and let $g_{\alpha \beta} : U_\alpha \cap U_\beta \to \mathrm{GL}(k, \mathbb C)$ be its transition functions. Then, as you correctly remarked, the transition functions of $\bar E$ are $\bar g_{\alpha \beta}$, which are antiholomorphic. 1/2

Comment: However, since $\mathrm{GL}(k, \mathbb C)$ is an invariant subset of $\mathbb C^{k \times k}$ under complex conjugation, you might as well endow it with the complex conjugate holomorphic atlas, and now $\bar g_{\alpha \beta}$ become holomorphic functions. 2/2